# asp.net db in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net MVC 1 application. I have asp.net db database in it. Can I add new tables in it and use them ? I see that I can  use asp.net profile in views but they are not accessible in controller and models. How can I access them in model?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Please try to clarify it. What database do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your are referring to the aspnet DB that stores the user credentials in it. Personally I would not add anything to an auto generated database, however there is a way you can get the aspnet DB **schema** into you own database, then it is a case of pointing your provider connection string in the web config to your own DB. This way you can consolidate and use the user data in your application.

To inject the aspnet DB schema into your own DB follow the steps laid out in this article, specifically Step 2 (the aspnet_regsql.exe tool)

http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs